# SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Conditional statements in external function

Tags: sql-server, function

I have a function which calls a CLR assembly

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetUTCDate](@LocalDate [datetime])
RETURNS [datetime] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [MyAssembly].[MyClassName].[GetUTCDateTime]
GO
```

I need to add conditional statement inside this function like if @LocalDate is a particular date then return some other value else use the assembly, like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fGetUTCDate](@LocalDate [datetime])
RETURNS [datetime] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
BEGIN
RETURN
 CASE WHEN @LocalDate = 'xxxxx' THEN 'XYZ' ELSE
    EXTERNAL NAME [MyAssembly].[MyClassName].[GetUTCDateTime]
END
END
GO
```

However, it seems I cannot add conditional statements inside this function.

My restrictions in current requirement are:
a) I cannot modify the assembly
b) The function is used in more than 250 SPs so I cannot create another function which calls this external function.

Is there any other way possible to achieve my requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Why this cannot be added inside the conditional statement?

Comment: function does not compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

1) Rename existing function

2) Create a new function with IF logic with the old name that calls the old function